# how to give topLeftRadius for RTL support app?

Tags: android

I want rectangle with left top and left bottom radius as 5 and remaining with 0dp. it is working fine for LTR, But In case RTL, How can I give ?
Is there any way like StartTop ..

Here is my xml code,

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
        <!--<corners android:radius="1dp"/>-->
        <!-- You can create different radius for different corners -->
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:topRightRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
            />
        </shape>
    </item>
    </selector>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Jul I have created two separate xml and based on the lang I set the drawable programmatically

Comment: Thank you for your answer Saranya